# Gson malformedJsonException when casting Json string to object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have created a Json string using `Gson` which is valid.I used following way to create the Json object.

```
Map myMap=new HashMap();
myMap.put("dryRunTest",dryRunTestObj);
myMap.put("port",22);
myMap.put("Repository",RepositoryObj);
etc...

Map temp = new HashMap();
temp.put("configuration",myMap);
new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(temp);
//This gave me the below Json Object that would write to a file.

{
  "configuration": {
    "dryRunTest": {
      "id": null,
      "defaultName": "sample.xml",
      "ParamsMap": null,
      "defaultVersion": "1.2",
      "dryRunTestOn": true
    },
    "port": 2323,
    "ip": "11.11.11.111",
    "configFile": "config.json",
    "Name": "007",
    "URL": "http://11.111.111.51/ma/api/ag/",
    "Password": "123",
    "configDirectory": "sss",
    "platform": "Windows7",
    "Repository": {
      "repositoryURL": "http://11.11.111.11/"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to create `Repository` object using Repository Json string like following.

```
class Repository{
String repositoryURL;
getter and setters
}
```

Then i desalinize serialize Json object using,

```
 Map mymap= new Gson().fromJson(JsonObjectReadFromFile(aboveString), HashMap.class);

RepositoryJsonStringvalue = mymap.get("Repository");

Repository r=new Gson().fromJson(RepositoryJsonStringvalue, Repository.class);
```

It return following exception.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 21
```

Seems like problem was with it value `repositoryURL` but i put same value into another top level attribute `URL=http://11.11.111.11/` and then can get values but when it put inside object type it throws that error.Please let me know how to fix this.

**Note**:I found out problem was in `repositoryURL` attribute if i remove special characters `: \` from string i can cast to the Repository object.So i would like to know how can i put URL`http://11.11.111.11/` in to json object even my above object is valid Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POJO class should be as follows:-

I have not included all the fields in the below POJO classes. You can include and try.

**ParentConfiguration class:-**

```
public class ParentConfiguration implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1185592608319193198L;

    private Configuration configuration;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ParentConfiguration [configuration=" + configuration + "]";
    }


}
```

**Configuration class:-**

```
public class Configuration implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Configuration [port=" + port + ", URL=" + URL + ", repository=" + repository + "]";
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8642243843212797330L;

    private Integer port;

    private String URL;



    @SerializedName("Repository")
    private Repository repository;

}
```

**Repository class:-**

```
public class Repository implements Serializable{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Repository [repositoryURL=" + repositoryURL + "]";
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1891563116357617243L;
    private String repositoryURL;

}
```

**Main method:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{  \"configuration\": {\"dryRunTest\": {\"id\": null,\"defaultName\": \"sample.xml\",      \"ParamsMap\": null,      \"defaultVersion\": \"1.2\",      \"dryRunTestOn\": true    },    \"port\": 2323,    \"ip\": \"11.11.11.111\",    \"configFile\": \"config.json\",    \"Name\": \"007\",    \"URL\": \"http://11.111.111.51/ma/api/ag/\",    \"Password\": \"123\",    \"configDirectory\": \"sss\",    \"platform\": \"Windows7\",    \"Repository\": {      \"repositoryURL\": \"http://11.11.111.11/\"    }  }}";


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ParentConfiguration parentConfiguration = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ParentConfiguration.class);
        System.out.println(parentConfiguration.toString());
    }
```

**Output:-**

```
ParentConfiguration [configuration=Configuration [port=2323, URL=http://11.111.111.51/ma/api/ag/, repository=Repository [repositoryURL=http://11.11.111.11/]]]
```

**Instead of converting to Map if you can parse it as JsonObject, you can easily achieve the result:-**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

JsonObject jsonObject= new Gson().fromJson(IOUtils.toString(ParseUrl.class.getResourceAsStream("/configuration.json")), JsonObject.class);
        Repository respository = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("configuration").get("Repository"), Repository.class);
        System.out.println(respository);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have updated the post with more details please refer.I want cast to  `Repository` object.seems like problem was `repositoryURL`  it contains some unterminated values.

Comment: Added another way to parse and get repository object.

Comment: Thanks you saved my time.it works fine.few clarifications is there any relation with overriding `toString` for Json serialization and deserialization.or it is enough putting `@SerializedName` on field.can you please explain why my previous code got exceptions.

Comment: There is no relation between toString and @SerializedName (used to mention the Json key name in POJO if it is different from POJO variable name). I believe your code was throwing exception because RepositoryJsonStringvalue was just having the string value of the object (i.e. not a JSON string with double quotes etc.). You can run in debug mode or sysout to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the string to json string  before converting it to object via gson.
This happens in case of a map where you get an object if you do  map.get(key).

The object wont have quotes "" around key or value.

While converting to json  before , will ensure that.

```
RepositoryJsonStringvalue = mymap.get("Repository");
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(RepositoryJsonStringvalue).toString();
Repository r=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Repository.class);
```

Hope it helps